# Detect time required to download file in client machine

Tags: asp.net

suppose there is a provision for downloading file from my site. so user can download file from site. i want to show info like how much time will be requited to download file in client machine. every client will have different internet speed so how can i detect and show time required to download file in client machine. is it possible in asp.net. please help me with sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant give you a sample,, But I can give you an general idea to do it. You can let the page when it is fully loaded do an ajax call to a asp.net page that return around 1mb of dummy data. The javascript saves the timestamp when it starts the ajax call,, and saves the timestamp when the 1mb call is completed. the difference between the 2 timestamp is how long the connection will do about 1mb of data. With that knowledge you can calculate how long it will take for the download of XX mb.

Answer (score 1):

A method I have seen on Microsoft's website for downloads is they provide a list of generally used speeds in a `ComboBox`.

It lets the user know how much time it will take with each type of connection.

### Example:

[Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (Web Installer)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992)

[image]